# Sass BEM: avoid modifier duplication when element is inside a modifier

Tags: sass, bem

Can I somehow refactor the following code snippet to get rid of **double modifier declaration**?

```
.block {
  &__element {
    rule: value;
  }
  &--modifier {
    rule: value;
  }
  &--modifier & {
    &__element {
      rule: value;
    }
  }
}
```

Output wanted:

```
.block {
   property: value;
}
.block--modifier {
  property: value;
}
.block--modifier .block__element {
  property: value;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nesting elements inside modifiers is a **known issue**. There are a lot of workarounds.

## Variable way

#### Store the block element in a variable.

And use it interpolated when creating a element inside a modifier.

```
.block {
  $block: &;

  &__element {
    property: value;
  }

  &--modifier {
    property: value;
    #{$block}__element {
      property: value;
    }
  }
}
```

> See output below.

## Function way

#### 1. Create a function that returns the block element.

It'll get the parent selector and cut the word before `--` (which is the block). Looks hacky, but it's the simplest way to go.

```
@function block() {
  $selector: str-slice(inspect(&), 2, -2);
  $index: str-index($selector, '--') - 1;
  @return str-slice($selector, 0, $index);
}
```

#### 2. Use the function interpolated.

Which will return the name of the block so you don't have to repeat it.

```
.block {
  property: value;

   &--modifier {
     property: value;
     #{block()}__element {
       property: value;
     }
   }
}
```

> See output below.

### Both ways will output to:

```
.block {
  property: value;
}

.block--modifier {
  property: value;
}

.block--modifier .block__element {
  property: value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've also found a wonderful [BEM-constructor](https://github.com/danielguillan/bem-constructor). Unfortunately at the moment it doesn't work with libsass, but it probably will when 3.3 version is released.

Comment: Now to find a solution for when creating elements and modifiers using a mixin.

Comment: BTW, the variable way will not output
`.block--modifier .block__element {property: value;}`
it will output:
`.block--modifier .block--modifier__element {property: value;}`

Answer (score 1):

You can place the block within the `&--modifier` selector like this, using the class name of the block rather than `&` to target it.

```
.block {
  &__element {
    rule: value;
  }
  &--modifier {
    rule: value;

    .block {
      &__element {
        rule: value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this is possibly not the best BEM solution, you should consider renaming the nested block as an element of the containing block, such as `.block__another-element` or creating a new block entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `&` alongside the modifier for a solution similar to Toni's.

```css
.block {

  &__element {
    rule: value;
  }

  &--modifier & {
    rule: value;
    
    &__element {
      rule: value;
    }
  }
}
```

This would however require `.block` to be a root selector and not nested inside any other selector.

Just another possible solution. For most situations though, I would still prefer Toni's solution.

Comment: This is how I do it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

if someone use less, this will help you!

```less
@block:.parent;
@{block}{
    backgroung:red;
    &--modifier{
        backgroung:blue;
    }
    &__child{
        font-size:20px;
        @{block}--modifier & {
           font-size:40px;
        }
    }
}
```